# external js file loaded but the code don't working

Tags: javascript, module, external-js

when I write js code internally in the html file It's work well.
hre is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="./cs.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="root" onload="App">
   

</div>
<script src="js/App.js" type="module" />
</body>
</html>
```

and here is App.js file

```
import Insert from './Insert.js';
function App(){
  document.getElementById("root").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin",'<h1>hello Javascript</h1>');
};
```

Comment: You need parentheses to call a function: `onload="App()"`

Comment: Also, `onload` doesn't fire on DIVs. Move that to `<body>`

Comment: Hello Atiye Naderi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try searching about the problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. `onload` is not an attribute supported by `div` elements, generally if you use it you would apply it to the `body` element, but it should be avoided in favour of `addEventListener`
2. The value of the `onload` attribute is the body of a JS function. Just mentioning the name of another function doesn't do anything. If you want to call a function you would usually follow the name with `()`.
3. `type="module"` loads a JS module, which (among other things) means the outer scope is the *module* and not the global scope so you can't access `App` anyway. Again, use `addEventListener`.
4. The `</script>` end tag for the `script` element is mandatory and you omitted it. (Since it was that last thing in the document it probably won't break anything, but you are opening yourself up for future problems).

Comment: thanks a lot   . would you please tell me what 'event' should I use for addEventListener in this case ?

Comment: `load` presumably.